# Code optimization - cicle

Tags: c, optimization

I want to do a large block of code until at least one of the elements of  array 1 is equal to 1 of the elements of array 2.

I'm asking the community to share, if possible, the best(fastest to process) ways possible to do this "while"

*Sum up:*

```
while (none of the elements from arr1 is equal to any of arr2)

{ 
    (code)
}
```

Reason: In my code, depending on some dimensions set by the user, my program may need to make this n^2 complexity comparison a lot of times, so I'm looking for a way to make it as light as I can.

I'm sorry in advance, and please let me know, if this type of questions are not suitable for StackOverflow.

Edit: My bad in not giving information about the arrays. As I said, it's dimension may vary based on what the user choses, but each one's size should be between 3 and 1000. Both arrays of integers.

Their values do change, the bigger the dimensions, the more it can happen.

Comment: What size are `arr1` and `arr2` — tens, hundreds, thousands, millions of elements?  What's the type of the elements in the arrays?  Are they simple integers or complete structures, or what?  Does it make sense to use hashes, to compare the hashes, and check for full equality only if the hashes are equal?  Does either array change?  How much does each array change?

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to use a hash mapping elements to pairs of integer counts. When you add E to arr1, increment count1 of the entry E-><count1,count2>. Similarly for arr2 and count2. Also maintain a single integer total T of the number of entries with both counts greater than zero. You can update these structures in constant time each time an entry in arr1 or arr2 changes or is added/deleted. Then the loop becomes `while (T > 0)`. OTOH if the code block is big and slow, this may be premature optimization. Comparing a million ints is probably fine if the block takes a second to run.

Comment: Can you sort those arrays, or they cannot be changed? Because if you could sort them it may be much easier.

Comment: From what I think, you cannot sort them

Answer (score 0):

The comments mention a hash and I agree, it could work, but it's very size-dependent. `O(n^2)`'s overhead will be negligible a lot of the time.

Otherwise, just add all the elements of `arr1` into the hashset, then go through `arr2`'s elements to see if they're in there. You'll get `O(n)` time. Honestly though, unless you're working with elements in the hundred thousands, even millions, I don't think the pay-out will be that tangible, but it's machine dependent and I haven't tested it myself.

C++ has std::unordered_set in the standard. If you're using pure C, I'm sure there's implementations available online.